# Using GoogleContainerTools/jib only to build without deploy?

Tags: docker, maven, jib

I'd like to use [jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) but only for building an image and not deploying it to the cloud or dockerhub.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jib supports also building an image without sending it to a remote registry, e.g. with the Gradle plugin you can run:

```
gradle jibDockerBuild
```

instead of:

```
gradle jib
```

It also supports commands like `gradle jibBuildTar` to build the image and store it in a tar file.

Comment: I'm using Maven. What's the equivalent please?

Comment: Oh, I believe it's `mvn compile jib:dockerBuild`